# How to retrieve data from glacier while controlling retrieval costs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I need to make an application which is required to retrieve sets of data from amazon glacier to S3. The application is usually aware of any data requests much prior to the requirement. I need to distribute the retrieval in the manner that the overall cost of retrieval is minimized. The retrieval from S3 console doesn't ask for the retrieval and occurs as fast as 4 hours which results in huge costs.

Are there any free available options for Linux. On searching, I found several paid softwares mostly for the windows platform. I think a simple piece of code should do the work but I am not able to set the option for the retrieval time.

**Edit:** I have written this code to spread the retrieval request over a longer period. Will this decrease my cost compared to one single retrieval?

```
aws s3 ls s3://<bucket_name>/origGlacier/ | awk '{if ($4) print $4}' > glacierFiles

for i in `cat glacierFiles`
  do
    aws s3api restore-object --bucket <bucket_name> --key $i --restore-request Days=30
    sleep 360
done
```

Comment: Requests for tool/library/utility recommendations are off-topic; note, though, that there is no way to ask glacier to delay a retrieval.  If you want to optimize your costs by spreading out your requests over time, that is what you have to do -- wait, before making the next request.  Once made, a retrieval request is always assumed, for billing purposes, to occur over the next 4 hours from the time the request is made.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I am more interested in programming solutions than a software tool as I shall be using the method inside a web application. I have added a piece of code which I am not sure will decrease the cost compared to single retrieval.

Comment: You probably need a bit more sophistication than that, since retrieval requests started in the same hour appear to be billed together.